# What causes infinite template recursion in this tensor outer product?

Tags: c++, templates, math, template-meta-programming

I'm implementing the outer product using a templated representation of a Tensor.

The basic prototype of the tensor looks like:

```
template <int N>
struct Tensor
{
    Tensor<N - 1> x;
    Tensor<N - 1> y;
    Tensor<N - 1> z;
};
```

With a specialization for `Tensor<1>` to degrade to a simple vector. My `Outer` function is defined as:

```
template <int N, int M>
Tensor<N + M> Outer(const Tensor<N> &lhs, const Tensor<M> &rhs)
{
    Tensor<N + M> result;

    result.x = Outer(lhs.x, rhs);
    result.y = Outer(lhs.y, rhs);
    result.z = Outer(lhs.z, rhs);

    return result;
}

template <int N>
Tensor<N + 1> Outer(const Tensor<N> &lhs, const Tensor<1> &rhs)
{
    Tensor<N + 1> result;

    result.x = Outer(lhs.x, rhs);
    result.y = Outer(lhs.y, rhs);
    result.z = Outer(lhs.z, rhs);

    return result;
}

template <>
Tensor<2> Outer(const Tensor<1> &lhs, const Tensor<1> &rhs)
{
    Tensor<2> result;

    result.x.x = lhs.x * rhs.x;
    result.x.y = lhs.x * rhs.y;
    result.x.z = lhs.x * rhs.z;

    // and so on

    return result;
}
```

The outer product of a tensor `A` of order `N` and of a tensor `B` of order `M` is simply the outer product of each element of `A` with the `B` tensor. The outer product of any tensor of order `N` with a tensor of order `1` is defined similarly.

The base case is simply the outer product of two order `1` tensors (vectors). Except, as defined above I'm getting a `C1202` error in MSVC:

> error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex

What did I do wrong in my definition of an outer product?

Comment: Works fine for me on VS11 beta. What number are you using? Are you sure you specialised it?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/LcKdP) with VC10 SP1. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ildjarn: http://pastebin.com/rTU1c5BC This minimal example causes the C1202 error in VS 2010 Ultimate SP1.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It's defined and implemented within a header only, and the versions being used are `N = 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: Could Tensor<1> being declared after the specialized functions using it the issue in your example?

Comment: @Morwenn: That's exactly the reason why. I happened to just through the `Outer` definition in a random place when I wrote it, which happened to be before the specialization of `Tensor<1>`.

Comment: Well, it was the issue. I tried to compile your piece of code and it caused my computer to crash. Twice. Because I wanted to make sure.
I tried it with exhcanging the places and it just worked fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This builds cleanly for me:

```
template<int N>
struct Tensor
{
    Tensor<N - 1> x;
    Tensor<N - 1> y;
    Tensor<N - 1> z;

    Tensor() { }

    Tensor(const Tensor<N-1>& X, const Tensor<N-1>& Y, const Tensor<N-1>& Z)
      : x(X), y(Y), z(Z)
    { }
};

template<>
struct Tensor<1>
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    Tensor() : x(), y(), z() { }
    Tensor(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    { }
};

template<int N, int M>
Tensor<N + M> Outer(const Tensor<N>& lhs, const Tensor<M>& rhs)
{
    Tensor<N + M> result;

    result.x = Outer(lhs.x, rhs);
    result.y = Outer(lhs.y, rhs);
    result.z = Outer(lhs.z, rhs);

    return result;
}

template<int N>
Tensor<N + 1> Outer(const Tensor<N>& lhs, const Tensor<1>& rhs)
{
    Tensor<N + 1> result;

    result.x = Outer(lhs.x, rhs);
    result.y = Outer(lhs.y, rhs);
    result.z = Outer(lhs.z, rhs);

    return result;
}

template<int N>
Tensor<N + 1> Outer(const Tensor<1>& lhs, const Tensor<N>& rhs)
{
    return Outer(rhs, lhs);
}

Tensor<2> Outer(const Tensor<1>& lhs, const Tensor<1>& rhs)
{
    Tensor<2> result;

    result.x.x = lhs.x * rhs.x;
    result.x.y = lhs.x * rhs.y;
    result.x.z = lhs.x * rhs.z;
    result.y.x = lhs.y * rhs.x;
    result.y.y = lhs.y * rhs.y;
    result.y.z = lhs.y * rhs.z;
    result.z.x = lhs.z * rhs.x;
    result.z.y = lhs.z * rhs.y;
    result.z.z = lhs.z * rhs.z;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Tensor<4> a;
    Tensor<4> b;
    Outer(a, b);
}
```

The notable changes are:

1. The `Tensor<1>` specialization needs to be defined before any of the `Outer` overloads.
2. The `Tensor<1>` specialization needs to be default-constructible, since `Tensor<2>` will attempt to default-construct its `x`, `y`, and `z` data members.
3. A `template<int N> Tensor<N + 1> Outer(const Tensor<1> &lhs, const Tensor<N> &rhs)` overload is needed for symmetry with `template<int N> Tensor<N + 1> Outer(const Tensor<N> &lhs, const Tensor<1> &rhs)`, or you need to add an overload that takes a `double` for `lhs`.
4. Remove `template<>` from the `Tensor<2> Outer(const Tensor<1> &lhs, const Tensor<1> &rhs)` overload – we're *overloading* here, not specializing.

Comment: I figured it out right as you posted this -- It's because I had the base case definition of `Tensor<1>` defined AFTER the outer product.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know you made modifications.